# How to detect in Iron Python what the script is being called from?

Tags: .net, mono, ironpython

I have a ipy script that can be called either from an embedded console in a larger application or directly from the command line and I'm looking for a quick way to determine at run time which has occurred without having to pass an argument to differentiate the events.

Additionally the script has to run on both mono/linux and .net/windows.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` (assuming you don't use AppDomain isolation, of course) and see if that contains an assembly that would only be preset when your application is running.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the way you run the embedded code, but the common way to check if a script is run from command line is:

```
if __name__=='__main__': ....
```

That should work also in your case. Regarding the platform check `sys.platform`.

Comment: Unfortunately the way we embed the script in the application seems to trip this check. But sys.platform is useful